# How to Generate dynamic email accounts with domain like abc@domain.com, xyz@domain.com using php

Tags: php, email

I want to generate email account dynamically when user register. email account will be with domain like username1@domain.com, username2@domain.com.

I want to this feature integration with PHP script.

Please kindly give solution or suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create emails accounts using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870117/create-emails-accounts-using-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's the backend you use to handle these accounts?

Comment: @NicoHaase Backend is Laravel. I am not sure from where to start.

Comment: Laravel won't handle any email account, and PHP itself will (most probably) neither do that. You must be using any mail server in the backend which needs to know all accounts, and you should start checking it for such extensions before you start to implement anything in PHP

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, I found solution from cpanel by contacting them.